# Is it a good idea to update a gem to a previous version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install [jimson](https://github.com/chriskite/jimson) gem in my Rails 4.2 app :

Gemfile :

```
gem 'jimson', '~> 0.10.0'
```

After bundle, I get this error :

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rack (1.6.0)

  In Gemfile:
    jimson (~> 0.10.0) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4.5) ruby
```

As the error says, **jimson depends on rack 1.4.5**, and **my current rack version is 1.6.0**

(I already get the same error with multi_json gem and I downgrade it from 1.11.0 to 1.7.6 and now it asks me to downgrade to rack 1.4.5 !!)

Is it a good idea to replace rack 1.6.0 with rack 1.4.5 ? I am not sure if there is another solution to use jimson without modifying the installed gems !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading rack wouldn't work because rails 4.2 requires rack 1.6.

It is entirely possible that this gem would work with newer versions of rack - 1.4.5 was probably just the current version at the time.

To test this theory you would need to fork the gem and update the dependency. I'd check that the gems tests/specs still run and you can then add your fork of the gem to your app as a :git dependency. Also consider sending a pull request to the original author.

In this case you don't need to do any of this because someone has already created such a [pull request](https://github.com/chriskite/jimson/pull/28), and the travis specs pass for that pull request, so you'd just need to merge the changes from that pull request into your fork

Comment: how I can merge that pull request, it's noted at the bottom "Only those with write access to this repository can merge pull requests"

Comment: You can't merge that pull request - you'd have to fork the repository and apply the changes in the pull request to your fork.

Comment: I end up forking the fork made by the owner of that pull request so I don't have to do that :) thank you for your answers they were very helpful.